# Oracle sqldeveloper Export data is lack when I get mass of metadata

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, metadata, ddl

Data lack is happen when I execute following query and export tsv from wizard.

--query

```
Select 
 view_name
 , replace(replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl(‘VIEW’, view_name), ‘“‘,’’), concat(user, ‘.’),’’) as ddl
From user_views
order by view_name;
```

--result

```
"VIEW_NAME" | "DDL"
"V_EQUITY" |
" CREATE OR REPLACE FORECE EDITABLE VIEW...
…"
"V_MATERIAL" |
" CREATE OR REPLACE FORECE EDITABLE VIEW V_MATERIAL (XXXX,XXXXX,XXXXX,...
XXXX,....) AS
 SELECT
  XXXX
  ,XXXX
  ,XXXX
  ,XXXX
 FROM
  (SELECT * FROM XXXX) MT
  LEFT O"
```

-> Actually query is continued but some view is lacked.
Maybe it is too long but I don't know the limit.

It is confusing it is no problem when I try following query and export tsv file.

--query
select 
view_name
, replace(replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl(‘VIEW’, view_name), ‘“‘,’’), concat(user, ‘.’),’’) as ddl
from user_views where view_name = 'V_MATERIAL'
order by view_name;

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly how you are exporting and what options you are choosing - are you running the query as a statement, going to the Query Result tab, right-clicking, choosing export? Or something else? And which version of SQL Developer, in case that makes a difference? (If you were running as a script I'd suggest you `set long 32767`, but it doesn't sound like you are.)

Answer (score 0):

That returns a LOB, so you need to SET LONG such that the text doesn't get truncated.

Also, your code has SMART QUOTES in it..that won't work. They are less than helpful, thanks Microsoft.

```
clear screen
set long 1000

Select
view_name
, replace(replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', view_name), '"',''), concat(user, '.'),'') as ddl
From user_views
where view_name = 'EMP_DETAILS_VIEW'
order by view_name;
```

And the output -

```
VIEW_NAME                                                                                                                        DDL                                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EMP_DETAILS_VIEW                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                   CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW EMP_DETAILS_VIEW (EMPLOYEE_ID, JOB_ID
                                                                                                                                 , MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION_ID, COUNTRY_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SAL
                                                                                                                                 ARY, COMMISSION_PCT, DEPARTMENT_NAME, JOB_TITLE, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, COUNTRY_N
                                                                                                                                 AME, REGION_NAME) DEFAULT COLLATION USING_NLS_COMP  AS                          
                                                                                                                                   SELECT                                                                        
                                                                                                                                   e.employee_id,                                                                
                                                                                                                                   e.job_id,                                                                     
                                                                                                                                   e.manager_id,                                                                 
                                                                                                                                   e.department_id,                                                              
                                                                                                                                   d.location_id,                                                                
                                                                                                                                   l.country_id,                                                                 
                                                                                                                                   e.first_name,                                                                 
                                                                                                                                   e.last_name,                                                                  
                                                                                                                                   e.salary,                                                                     
                                                                                                                                   e.commission_pct,                                                             
                                                                                                                                   d.department_name,                                                            
                                                                                                                                   j.job_title,                                                                  
                                                                                                                                   l.city,                                                                       
                                                                                                                                   l.state_province,                                                             
                                                                                                                                   c.country_name,                                                               
                                                                                                                                   r.region_name                                                                 
                                                                                                                                 FROM                                                                            
                                                                                                                                   employees e,                                                                  
                                                                                                                                   departments d,                                                                
                                                                                                                                   jobs j,                                                                       
                                                                                                                                   locations l,                                                                  
                                                                                                                                   countries c,                                                                  
                                                                                                                                   regions r                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id                                         
                                                                                                                                   AND d.location_id = l.location_id                                             
                                                                                                                                   AND l.country_id = c.country_id                                               
                                                                                                                                   AND c.region_id = r.region_id                                                 
                                                                                                                                   AND j.job_id = e.job_id                                                       
                                                                                                                                 WITH READ ONLY
```

Or a picture :)

[image]